# Why does in_array return false for this search?

Tags: php, arrays, php-7

Why does below code return `false`? It ought to return true.

```
in_array(
    '/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/SJ-R42027-CZ-SG-1-scaled-1.jpg',
    [
        'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/SJ-R42027-CZ-SG-1-scaled-1.jpg'
    ],
    false
)
```

[Online code editor](https://paiza.io/projects/MQpx8QfspqGk71st-z_hwg)

Comment: `in_array()` expects the search value to exist as a complete value, you want it to be a partial match by the look of it.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php would be more appropriate based on what you're trying to do. And if you need to search in multiple values, then you can write a loop to iterate through or use array_map().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood the "strict" argument. Eg.

```
in_array('3', [1, 2, 3, 4], true); // ==> false because the string '3' !== 3
```

However if you don't pass a third argument or pass it `false`:

```
in_array('3', [1, 2, 3, 4]);        // ==> true because '3' == 3
in_array('3', [1, 2, 3, 4], false); // ==> true because '3' == 3
```

However in your case the strings don't match even with loose `==`:

```
'/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/SJ-R42027-CZ-SG-1-scaled-1.jpg' == 
    'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/SJ-R42027-CZ-SG-1-scaled-1.jpg'
// ==> false
```

Answer (score 3):

It is correct behavior.

There is no string `/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/SJ-R42027-CZ-SG-1-scaled-1.jpg` in that array.